# Force client to provide implementation of an innerclass when extending an outerclass

Tags: java, iterator, abstract-class, inner-classes, iterable

I was wondering if it is possible to force clients to provide an implementation of an innerclass when they define a new implementation of the outerclass.

To explain the situation better: I've an abstract class

```
public abstract class ImmutablePolynomial implements Iterable {

    protected int degree;

    static ImmutablePolynomial sum(ImmutablePolynomial x, ImmutablePolynomial y) {
        .... Some Implementation using an iterator over terms and a return statement....
     }

     public abstract TermIterator iterator();

     Here I want an innerclass (TermIterator) extending Iterator that must be implemented 
     if you extend ImmutablePolynomial.
```

Now the client can provide an implementation of an ImmutablePolynomial, using a specific datastructure to for example reduce memory usage, by extending this class.
How can I force the client to also provide an implementation of an Innerclass Implementing Iterator such that the static method sum in ImmutablePolynomial also works with the implementation provided by the client?

Also if this is a bad idea / antipattern / there is a better alternative please tell me so. I'm doing this to improve my coding.

Edit 1: remove the field

> protected Collection terms

, as is adviced in the comments.
Edit 2: make method

> iterator()

abstract as is adviced in the comments

Comment: No, there isn't a way to do this.  Why do you need them to use a different iterator implementation?

Comment: Why not make the iterator() method abstract? Subclasses must implement it. Also make TermIterator an interface and you're set. However I do not like that you have the `Collection terms` field; why not let the subclass decide how to do it?

Comment: @LouisWasserman The iterator is supposed to go over the terms in descending order of exponents. So if you have 4x^2 +3x + 1 it must first give the term 4X^2 then 3x and then 1. This is because of the method sum

Comment: @Ph03n1x, what does the default implementation do in that case?  How does `TermIterator` behave?

Comment: (It looks like you don't actually have a `TermIterator` class, in which case @TassosBassoukos has the right answer: just make the method abstract.)

Comment: @TassosBassoukos First about the Collection terms field i agree it is better to let the subclass decide, i will edit that. About the TermIterator if i change that to an interface must the subclass then also provide an implementation for it or is it still possible to not implement it then?

Comment: @LouisWasserman I did not want to provide a default implementation because of the constraint i put on the order in which it should give the terms. And i thought that the implementation depends on the chosen datastructure representing the term (The iterator implemenation of a List would be different to that of a Set or Map)

Comment: @Ph03n1x, okay, if you don't want a default implementation, then `iterator()` should be left abstract, and the subclasses should decide how to implement it -- maybe by implementing an inner `TermIterator` class themselves, maybe by reusing another `Iterator` implementation, or whatever.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given that the `ImmutablePolynomial` class is abstract, so that you will never have an object whose class is `ImmutablePolynomial`, and given you don't want instances of `ImmutablePolynomial`'s subclasses to use class `ImmutablePolynomial.TermIterator`, when would `ImmutablePolynomial.TermIterator` *ever* be used?  It is pointless to implement it as an inner class.

As @Tassos suggested in comments, declare `TermIterator` as an interface instead; this may be nested in class `ImmutablePolynomial` or not, as you prefer.  Also make `ImmutablePolynomial.iterator()` abstract.

To the extent that you have any concrete methods in `ImmutablePolynomial` that rely on the iterator, implement them against the interface instead of against any particular implementation.  That's the only sane approach anyway when you not only allow but require subclasses to supply their own implementation.